# Making a link bold, immediately after HTML has been loaded and with out any event occur?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

`alert()` is working fine, but when I tried to make a link bold, it is not working.

I think it is because of page is already loaded. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/8wmsk4Lk/ check this

Comment: And your code is..... in my crystal ball?

Comment: Why can't you just use <strong> or a css class since you have to make it bold from the start?

Comment: Hi Alberto, I need because, I only wanted to bold the link of the current page not all. Anyways I am done with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it using jquery:

```
$("selector").css('font-weight', 'bold');
```

Answer (score 1):

**Using Jquery:**

Use `ready()` to make a function available after the document is loaded:

The ready event occurs when the DOM (document object model) has been loaded.

Because this event occurs after the document is ready, it is a good place to have all other jQuery events and functions.

The ready() method specifies what happens when a ready event occurs.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('selector').css('font-weight','bold');
});
```

**Using Javascript:**

The onload event is a standard event in the DOM, while the `ready()`
 event is specific to jQuery. The purpose of the ready event is that it should occur as early as possible after the document has loaded, so that code that adds functionality to the elements in the page doesn't have to wait for all content to load.

```
window.onload = function () {
   all your code goes here.
}
```

Comment: Thanks you for your great info. Good day!